# EventWaitHandle can be used across processes. And auto and manual reset events only within a single process?

Tags: c#, .net

EventWaitHandle can be used across processes. And auto and manual reset events only within a single process. Can you please confirm?

Documentation says that Auto/Manual are local and they don't take name parameter. So I think they are only for within a process. By the way, can they go across appdomain?

EventWaitHandle is the only named event or there any other mechanisms i can use. Basically I need to use event, but it should cross process.

Comment: No, same problem with an AppDomain.  Simply use EventWaitHandle directly.  Auto/ManualResetEvent are very simple classes with only a constructor that's empty.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#/.net:". That's what the tags are there for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto and Manual are the simplified version of EventWaitHandle that are synchronized within process. [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41acw8ct.aspx) can be used as named object that will provide inter process synchronization.